# How to "fake packages" for TeX Live on Arch Linux?

Tags: packages, texlive, linux, distributions, dependencies

How to "fake packages" for TeX Live on Arch Linux?

I installed TeX Live directly from the script rather than the Arch packages. However `pacman` is unaware that I installed it and tries to install `texlive-` packages when I install other science-related software.

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu --needed sagetex
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (6) dvisvgm-3.1.1-1  texlive-basic-2023.66594-19  texlive-bin-2023.66984-16
             texlive-latex-2023.66594-19  texlive-latexrecommended-2023.66594-19  sagetex-3.6.1-4

Total Installed Size:  120.16 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

I found [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) on how to trick the package manager but it was only for Debian-based distributions. How can I do the same on Arch?

Comment: I am moving to `manjaro`. I have installed `TeX Live` using an `AUR`. I think this should work better in your case. No?

Comment: @projetmbc It won't work better. Whether it works equally well and is easier to manage depends on the quality of the `PKGBUILD`. One of them installs into `/opt` which is not necessarily the best place. It's easier if you have things where documentation etc. expects. Also, if you do that, you have to install with root privileges. While the OP likely did that anyway, I prefer installing as an unprivileged user for security reasons. It is incredibly easy to create a dummy package on Arch (unlike Fedora, say). I don't see a reason to install TeX Live from AUR. A native installation is more KISS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my `PKGBUILD` for the dummy package I'm currently using on Arch:

```
pkgname=texlive-dummy-cfr
pkgver=2.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="TeX typesetting program"
arch=(i686 x86_64)
license=('custom')
provides=('tetex' 'texlive-bin' 'texlive-core' 'texinfo' 'texlive-basic')
conflicts=('tetex' 'texlive-bin' 'texlive-core' 'texlive-basic')
build() {
/bin/true
}
package() {
/bin/true
}
```

Build and install this in the usual way (as you would for any other AUR package).

In addition, I have the following lines in `/etc/pacman.conf` as a safety net:

```
IgnorePkg   = texlive-bin
IgnoreGroup = texlive-most texlive-lang
```

If you install or update something TeX-related, you should still be alert to problems. From time to time, the packaging changes and you need to adapt the `PKGBUILD` to prevent wholesale installation of the packaged versions.